# byte < 0xC0 byte < 0x80

Tags: ruby, string

Could someone help me to understand what this Ruby script is doing?

```
def clean_up dirty_text
  newstr = ""

  dirty_text.each_byte do |byte|
    newstr << if byte < 0x80
      byte.chr
    elsif byte < 0xC0
      "\xC2" + byte.chr
    else
      "\xC3" + (byte - 64).chr      
    end
  end

  newstr
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a crufty way of transcoding Latin-1 as UTF-8.

["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks you. I will go through that URL.